# "Formula parse error" when querying different document

Tags: google-sheets, google-query-language

I am attempting to have a cell in Sheet B display data from a cell in External / Remote Sheet A, but it results in "Formula parse error." (ETA detail to aid searches: displaying data in one Google Spreadsheet from a different Google Sheet.)

My query:
    `=Query(SheetA,sheet1!A:I,"select I WHERE A=3")`

I've also tried it this way:
    `=Query(SheetA,sheet1!$A:$I,"select I WHERE A=3",-1)`

Comment: Does `=QUERY(SheetA!$A:$I,"select I where A=3")` work?

Comment: I tried your suggestion, and got "Unable to parse query string for Function QUERY parameter 2: NO_COLUMNI"

Comment: I got slightly better results by using this:
`=QUERY("SheetA","Sheet1!A1:I100","select I where A = '3'")`
But the error now says _Function QUERY parameter 3 expects number values. But 'select I where A = '3'' is a text and cannot be coerced to a number._
(I did change Column A to number.)

Comment: Does column I exist in SheetA?

Comment: Column capital i does exist, but sometimes I get an error that it does not.
This formula does work:
`=importrange("SheetA","Sheet1!I3:I3")`
But it is not what I need.

Comment: Whoa wait. Are you trying to reference a sheet in a different spreadsheet ("workbook")?

Comment: Sorry, I am not real familiar with the correct way to use StackOverFlow; I will attempt to enter the answer that @AdamL suggested, and give credit appropriately. That answer works beautifully, and is what I have been searching for, for many, many hours. Thanks so much.

Comment: If you can mark your own answer as "answered", let's just go with that. Perhaps use words to the effect "when QUERY isn't directly referencing a range in the same spreadsheet, use `Colx` notation rather than column letters".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer courtesy of @AdamL (thank you, sir!). This was his answer that I found does work very well. When QUERY isn't directly referencing a range in the same spreadsheet, use Colx notation rather than column letters:

```
    =QUERY(importrange("NameofGoogleSheet","SheetTabName!A:Z"),"select Col9 where Col1=3")
```

*If referencing dynamically, use something like:*

`=QUERY(importrange("NameofGoogleSheet","SheetTabName!A:Z"),"select Col9 where Col1="&D19)`

It is also important to note that you must first connect the sheets to each other. Until this is done, you will get column errors, etc. This is done by selecting a cell of the sheet that will display the data, and putting in an IMPORTRANGE on it, which opens a dialog for connecting them. More info: https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093340?hl=en

I also realized (duh) that I was being stupid to have two separate files for each. I only need two sheets within the same document; 1 to serve as the database and the other to display the formatted data. I am using this for a pedigree application.

Answer (score -1):

I had a Formula Parse Error problem.  My mistake was that I had two brackets on my formula.  I deleted one set, and it was fixed.  I am not sure why, but it worked for me.

EXAMPLE:

`=SUM((AB450,AB432,AB422,AB415,AB405))` - THIS GAVE ME A FORMULA PARSE ERROR.

`=SUM(AB450,AB432,AB422,AB415,AB405)` - THIS IS THE ONE THAT WORKED